# how to show sum groupFooterTemplate in kendo grid UI

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have data and showing in kendo grid with group. Every group (Invoice No - VGBEL ) has a groupFooterTemplate but Quantity (LFIMG) column always 0,00. I need sum of Quantity every footer. Where is my mistake ? I searched on the internet but didnt find solution. I know  there is a little mistake but I didnt find it.

This my JS code.

```js
var kendoResource = getKendoResourceOptions();

            options.columns[0].groupFooterTemplate = 'Sipariş Toplamı:'; 

            options.columns[8].groupFooterTemplate = '#: data.LFIMG ? kendo.format("{0:C2}",data.LFIMG.sum): 0,00 #';  


            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        toolbar: [{ name: "excel", text: kendoResource.toolbar.messages.excel }],
                        excel: {
                            fileName: "DeliveryList.xlsx",
                            allPages: true,
                            filterable: true
                        },

                        groupable: kendoResource.groupable,
                        scrollable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: kendoResource.pageable,
                        columns: options.columns
                    });


        self.filterClick = function () {
            showLoading();
            mbisPost('Reports.Summary', "/api/TermoTeknikReportApi/DeliveryList", ko.toJS(self.filters), function (result) {
                if (result && result.length > 0) {                
                    self.showNoDataToDisplay(false);
                    
                var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                  data: result,                      
                                  pageSize: 100,
                                  group: {
                                        field: "VGBEL",
                                    },
                                  aggregate: [
                                      { field: "LFIMG", aggregate: "sum" }
                                    ]
                                });

                var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.setDataSource(dataSource); 

                    // element for which the tooltip is shown
                    grid.thead.kendoTooltip({
                        filter: "th",
                        content: function (e) {
                            var target = e.target; 
                            return $(target).text();
                        }
                    });
        
                }
                else {
                    self.showNoDataToDisplay(true);
                }

            }).error(function () { hideLoading(); }).done(function () { hideLoading(); });
        }
```

Screenshot of webpage

[image]

Comment: have you looked at this demo from Telerik's website: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates from what i can see and assume at this stage all you need to do is change the kendo.format("{0:C2}",data.LFIMG.sum) to kendo.format("{0:C2}",sum) although what condition are you actually checking on the data.LFMIG field is it something that naturally is a true/false value? assuming it is a  value surely you should be checking to see if it meets a specific value like data.LFMIG > 0

Comment: thank you for your comment. when I debug in chrome  "data.LFIMG"  is not empty or null its has a value.  I found solution. I changed dataSource code and my problem solved. I share my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed dataSource code. put the "aggregates" properties into the group

```js
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                  data: result,                      
                                  pageSize: 100,
                                  group: {
                                        field: "VGBEL",
                                        aggregates: [ { field: "LFIMG", aggregate: "sum" },{ field: "LFIMG_M", aggregate: "sum" }]  // this line
                                    },
                                  aggregate: [
                                      { field: "LFIMG", aggregate: "sum" },{ field: "LFIMG_M", aggregate: "sum" } 
                                    ]
                                });
```